# Trying to get HorizontalOffset, always returns 0

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, scroll, winrt-xaml, dependency-properties

I am writing an app with C#/xaml for Windows8 Metro.

I have a Scrollviewer and would like to get the horizontaloffset.

I tryed it with this:

```
private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanged_1(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(GetValue(ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffsetProperty));
    }
```

but i is always 0, althrough in the debugger it shows me an offset of 221.09 and i scrolled down!

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scrolled down - your horizontal offset wouldn't change unless you scrolled horizontally.

Perhaps your event handler isn't on the ScrollViewer itself and if that's the case - you would need to call GetValue on the SV itself, e.g.

```
private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanged_1(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(myScrollViewer.GetValue(ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffsetProperty));
}
```

or better yet just do this:

```
private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanged_1(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(myScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset);
}
```